# get radix from std::stoi

Tags: c++

is there any way I can know the radix/base of the number I passed to `std::stoi(str, nullptr, 0)`? Since paramater `0` means the base used is determined by the format in the sequence, the code must know the radix/base, so (how) can I get it?

Comment: [This `std::stoi` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) will tell you how it deduces the base. You could do the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), the following decision tree is used but not exposed to outside:

1. Sign is optional, if present does not determine the base. Following is used on first 2 characters if sign is not present or on 2nd and 3rd characters if a +/- was present as first character.
2. If the first character is not 0, base is decimal.
3. Otherwise, if the second character is not x or X, base is octal.
4. Otherwise, the base is hexadecimal.